# Use SQL Statement With String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a products table and i need to concat my string and my sql statements. Is there any way?

My purpose is that i want to define column names just one time in a string variable and i will use it alot of times. Otherwise my sql statements has alot of column name and it complex my code.

For example, i use this

```
DECLARE @MyStr NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ProdId,ProdName'
SELECT TOP 10 @MyStr FROM Products
```

Result is here
[image: SQL Result]

---

But i need the result as this.
[image: SQL Result 2]

Comment: You could use dynamic sql: [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: i think there is no change to use except sp_executesql

Comment: [This is an interesting article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/dynamic-sql-amp-sql-injection/ba-p/383196) about using dynamic sql trying to avoid Sql Injection.

Comment: You can only use parameters for simple values. Not for column names or table names. (And also not for the list in an `IN` (...) query)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL here. I also suggest you fix your design and *don't* store delimited data, and ideally use a table type parameter. This would look like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @Columns table (ColumnName sysname);
INSERT INTO @Columns (ColumnName)
VALUES(N'Column1'),(N'Column2');

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(ColumnName),N',') + @CRLF + 
              N'FROM dbo.Products;'
FROM @Columns;

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If you don't want to use a `table` type, you can use `STRING_SPLIT`:

```sql
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([Value]),N',') + @CRLF + 
              N'FROM dbo.Products;'
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Columns,',');
```